# State does not persist on page navigation flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod

i have an app and i am managing state with riverpod. Well i notice that on page navigation i lose the state and it resets to the initial state. Here is my code;

**provider**

```
final registerAuthControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<
 RegisterAuthController,
 AuthenticatingUser>((ref) => RegisterAuthController(ref.read));
```

**State Notifier Code**

```
class RegisterAuthController extends StateNotifier<AuthenticatingUser> {
RegisterAuthController(this._read) : super(AuthenticatingUser.initial());

final Reader _read;

void updateEmail(String email) async {
state = state.copyWith(authenticating: true);
final getEmail = await _read(authRepositoryProvider).checkEmail(email);
if (getEmail == 'Email Already Exists') {
  state = state.copyWith(authenticating: false, emailError: true);
}
state = state.copyWith(authenticating: false, email: email);
print(state);
}

void updatePersonalDetails(
   String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber) {
   state = state.copyWith(
    authenticating: false,
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber);
 print(state);
```

}
}

**State Class**
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

```
class AuthenticatingUser extends Equatable {
  final String? firstName;
  final String? lastName;
  final String? email;
  final String? phoneNumber;
  final String? password;
  final int? passcode;
  final String? img;
  final bool authenticating;
  final bool emailError;

  AuthenticatingUser(
      {this.firstName,
      this.lastName,
      this.email,
      this.phoneNumber,
      this.password,
      this.passcode,
      required this.authenticating,
      required this.emailError,
     this.img});

factory AuthenticatingUser.initial() {
  return AuthenticatingUser(
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    email: null,
    phoneNumber: null,
    passcode: null,
    password: null,
    authenticating: false,
    emailError: false,
    img: null);
  }

AuthenticatingUser copyWith(
  {String? firstName,
  String? lastName,
  String? email,
  String? phoneNumber,
  int? passcode,
  required bool authenticating,
  bool emailError = false,
  String? password,
  String? img}) {
 return AuthenticatingUser(
    authenticating: authenticating,
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    email: email,
    password: password,
    passcode: passcode,
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
    emailError: emailError,
    img: img);
}

  @override
  List<Object?> get props =>
      [firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber, password, img, authenticating];
}
```

**Page 1 On tap method**

```
 onTap: () => {
              print('object'),
              if (EmailValidator.validate(emailEditingController.text))
                {
                  context
                      .read(registerAuthControllerProvider.notifier)
                      .updateEmail(emailEditingController.text),
                },
              // notValid = true,
            },
```

the update email function's print state returns the state with the updated email but when navigate to the second page through a provider listener, and i update the state with the updatePersonalDetails function, i see that the authenticateduser.email state value is back to null. It's like the state is being reset after every page navigation. I want state to persist after page navigations. How can i accomplish that?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use `StateNotifier.autoDispose` but use normal `StateNotifier`. I think it might be disposed during the navigating.

Comment: I used StateNotifier but it still did the same thing